# How do I convert my time "bins" to continous for a time series analysis in R?

Tags: r, graph, time-series, modeling

With the following data:

```
#demo data:
set.seed(1234)

library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
n = 100
time= c(15, 30, 60, 90, 120, 180, 240, 300)
treat = factor(c("trt1", "trt2", "tr1+2", "trt1+2+3"))
intensity = c(sample(1:400, n, replace=TRUE))
              df <- expand.grid(time= time, treat = treat, intensity=intensity)
df <- data.frame(
                time= rep(df$time, each = 100),
                intensity = rep(df$intensity),
                treat = rep(df$treat, each = 100)
)
```

**I am looking to fit a model, eventually, which seeks to compare the fluctuations to a traditional dampened oscillator function from physics.** Here's a graphical look at my problem:
[image]

And it could be that I am being dumb about how to make time continuous here, but it's important that the values be retained and that it not just be a one-variable time series data frame. Otherwise, that's what I would've done. But there's a factor variable for treatment that should be retained as well.

***It should look more like this (excel quick graph) but I need to extract the mathematical guts of the function for such lines that would trace the peaks of the curve in the R output:***
[image]

A solution would involve both: 1) being able to reproduce the curve in R, and 2) generating the density data over time needed to start fitting polynomial models.

Comment: How do the dots in the second figure relate to the distributions in the first figure?  I recognize that the colors correspond to the treatments in both, but are the dots at the mean, median, or some other summary of the values in each distribution?

Comment: The dots are simply time points of measurement. The distributions are not supposed to be the same, because the picture of the one to match has too much identifying information. But they are of similar treatments.

Comment: So let's pick one dot to explain: at the first one from the left, that is a point at time = 0, but intensity of measurement (y) = high # of count of intensity at that level

Comment: thanks.  That was sort of my question, though.  In your example data, `df` which just has time and treatment (x-value and color), what are we supposed to use to calculate a y-value?  Also, `silence` wasn't defined in your demo data, I assumed it was supposed to be `silence=time` in the call to `expand.grid()`.

Comment: My mistake in the making of the dummy data - I needed to add the y-value and it should be in now. Also, note that the dummy data will not yield a similar distribution just because the intensities were randomly sampled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Density plot for the fake data:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=intensity, fill=treat)) + 
  geom_density(color="transparent", alpha=.25) + 
  facet_wrap(~as.factor(time), nrow=1) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

Now, if you wanted to make that into a line plot, you could calculate the highest density value for each treatment-time pair and then plot it:

```
df %>% group_by(treat, time) %>% 
  summarise(d = max(density(intensity)$y)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=d, colour=treat)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x="Time", y="Intensity")
```

[image]

The last part of your ask was to generate the density data over time.  If I understand what you want to do, you could do it as follows:

```
out <- df %>% group_by(treat, time) %>% 
  summarise(as.data.frame(density(df$intensity)[c("x", "y")]))

head(out)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   treat, time [1]
#   treat  time     x          y
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 tr1+2    15 -20.5 0.00000608
# 2 tr1+2    15 -19.6 0.00000838
# 3 tr1+2    15 -18.7 0.0000114 
# 4 tr1+2    15 -17.8 0.0000153 
# 5 tr1+2    15 -17.0 0.0000203 
# 6 tr1+2    15 -16.1 0.0000267
```

The `x` variable is the evaluation point for intensity and the `y` variable is the height of the density curve for that value of `x`.

Comment: Beautifully done. I added a smoothing layer just to show my boss more readily (they hate line graphs so that's my bad on not being specific), but otherwise this is perfect.